# Parse res.text Node express

Tags: node.js, json, express, fetch

I am retrieving a csv-file from a cloud based storage as res.text and need to convert it to json.

I am wondering if I should do the parsing in the return of fetchUrl or if I should do it in  the route (res.send)?

```
const fetchUrl = async () => {
  const URL_1 = 'https://file.csv'
  const res = await fetch(URL_1)
  return res.text()
}

router.get('/data', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
      const getAllData = await fetchUrl();
      console.log(getAllData, 'fetching?');
      res.send(getAllData);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
    //res.send({ message: err })
    // res.status(404).send(err)
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I made use of a custom function, that converts it to json in the 2nd .then. So that I won't have to fetch upon every call to the endpoint since the data does not change.
Like so:

```
let getAllData 

fetch('https://file.csv')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => {
    getAllData = csvToJSON(data)
    getAllData.forEach((item) => {
      item.startTime = new Date(item.startTime)
    })
  })
```